# Cross compile gopacket for linux under MacOS

Tags: go, cross-compiling

We want to build [gopacket](https://github.com/google/gopacket) for Linux under MacOS.

What we have tried.

1. `CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build`

Errors

```
..gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:30:22: undefined: pcapErrorNotActivated
..gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:52:17: undefined: pcapTPtr
..gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:64:10: undefined: pcapPkthdr
```

2. Try to do cross compile through docker [golang-crossbuild](https://github.com/elastic/golang-crossbuild)

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v /Users/my/server:/go/src/my/server \
  -w /go/src/my/server \
  -e CGO_ENABLED=1 \
  -e CGO_LDFLAGS+="-L/libpcap/libpcap-1.8.1-amd64" \
  docker.elastic.co/beats-dev/golang-crossbuild:1.16.4-main \
  --build-cmd "GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build . " \
  -p "linux/amd64"
```

Errors

```
...pcap/pcap_unix.go:34:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcap.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

Is there any better way to do cross compile gopacket for linux under MacOS?

Comment: If you're already building inside a linux container you're not really cross-compiling. You just need to install the prerequisites for the package, like libpcap and gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we solve it after installing `libpcap-dev`

First, we build one new docker based on golang-crossbuild

Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/beats-dev/golang-crossbuild:1.16.4-main

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpcap-dev
```

build script is

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v /Users/my/server:/go/src/my/server \
  -w /go/src/my/server \
  -e CGO_ENABLED=1 \
  -e CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc \
  -e CGO_LDFLAGS+="-L/libpcap/libpcap-1.8.1" \
  golang-new-builder:latest \
  --build-cmd "GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build . " \
  -p "linux/amd64"
```